# When do we pronounce "ay" instead of "e" when we see the letter "i" in a word?

Tags: pronunciation

We pronounce "e" in the word "infinite" but "ay" in the word "finite".

As I'm learning this language, this disturbs me a lot because I don't know if I have to pronounce "e" or "ay" when I read.

Comment: I think you are referring to the fact that "finite" is pronounced /faɪnaɪt/ (with two long vowels or diphthongs as in "I" or "eye"), whereas "infinite" is pronounced /ɪnfɪnət/ (with three short vowels)?  At any rate, I'm not sure there is a good answer: even native speakers sometimes mispronounce a word if they've learnt it from a book and haven't looked up how to pronounce it.

Comment: There may be some sort of pattern here, as there are some similar examples, e.g. "famous" / "infamous", where the "a" is long in the first one but short (in fact /ə/) in the second.  Or "potent" / "impotent", where the "o" is long in the first and short in the second.

Comment: @rjpond Yes, I'm exactly refering to what you said in your first comment.

Comment: @rjpond Thank you for your anwser, so do you suggest I should always listen the words I read ? It's quite sad if there isn't any deterministic pattern to apply in order to know how to pronounce :/

Comment: "Migrant"/"immigrant" is another pair where the long vowel becomes short in the "in-"/"im-" version.  However, there are others that have a long vowel in both words ("mobile"/"immobile") or short in both ("logical"/"illogical").  On the more general question see also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59128/how-do-native-speakers-guess-the-pronunciation-of-the-letters-in-a-word-they-s?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question (with a different, more phonological oriented title) in a sibling stack exchange network [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405876/unstressed-syllable-in-the-middle-of-the-word-always-schwa-sound).

preface: I suggest you read about the stress in English, and about the [Schwa sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) and the [Near-close near-front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel).

In a nutshell, English doesn't really like having "full" vowels in a middle-unstressed syllable. in this case, the vowel in that syllable will be reduced to either the schwa sound or the /ɪ/ sound.

**finite**: the stress is in the first syllable.
**infinite** - by adding the "in", we "steal" the stress to the "in" syllable, making the "fi" a middle-unstressed syllable, so it's reduced to the /ɪ/ sound.

there are more examples like this one, that by adding another syllable which "steals" or "revives" the stress from/into some syllable, the pronunciation of the word changes:

history (ˈhɪst**ə**ɹi) - historical (hɪˈst**ɔ**ːɹɪkəl)
memory (mɛm**ə**ɹi) - memorial (məˈm**ɔ**ːɹi.əl)
famous (f**eɪ**məs) - infamous (ɪnf**ə**məs).

In one of the comments, the following examples were given where an added syllable does not change the "original" pronunciation of the word:
"mobile"/"immobile" and "logical"/"illogical". this is a perfect example for this pattern. in these two words the added syllable *doesn't steal away the stress* from the "original word" and hence, its original pronunciation doesn't change.

> As I'm learning this language, this disturbs me a lot because I don't
>   know if I have to pronounce "e" or "ay" when I read.

that what makes English extremely irritating to learn and the only way to know how to pronounce a word is too look in the dictionary.